# Microsoft SQL Server, creating new table in server explorer

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

For a C# programming assignment I have to create a table in Microsoft SQL Server. I have Visual Studio 2013 and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 freshly installed. As I installed it I specified my user for admin access (this is on a laptop with only my user anyway). I can't seem to be able to fully follow my teacher's instructions for the assignment:

1. Create a new WPF project called StudentDb
2. Open Server Explorer (  View > Server Explorer )
3. Right click on Data Connections > Create New SQL Server Database
   The Create New SQL Server Database window opens
4. Select a Server name (default: `.\SQLEXPRESS`)
5. Choose Windows Authentication
6. Enter `College` as the new database name
7. Click OK
8. In Server Explorer you’ll find a new Database listed under Data Connections
9. Expand the College Database (by clicking the triangle left of the `College` database)
10. Right click Tables > Add New Table

On number 4, the only server that appeared was "MORTHOS" which is my computer name. (I am hoping that this is arbitrary). I was able to create a new DB named college. When I get to 6 I find that my progress grinds to a complete halt. I only have the options Refresh and properties and can't see where to add a new table as pictured here:

[image: Tables right click]

I know it has a valid connection, because it was able to successfully create the College database. I can even confirm that it has a good connection when I click "test":

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: in SQL Server Management Studio I do see myself under the logins:

[image]

Comment: Does the user your logging in with have access to create tables?

Comment: It should, I'm sure I added myself as such every time prompted during the installation. Is there any way to double check and/or add this?

Comment: Open sql management studio and connect to the server. In the explorer there should be a node called Security and under that should be your username. When you open the user there should be a section called "server roles" make sure sysadmin is checked.

Comment: You selected Windows Authentication while creating database. Try using SQL Server authentication and specify the credentials that you used while installing SQL Server. Also try creating tables by executing queries in the database.

Comment: try to connect to .\SQLEXPRESS and check if there you have option to create table

Comment: @donstack this question is about the full version of SQL Server.

Comment: i guessed from steps, well it is possible to have express with full version.

Comment: @P_G I do see myself listed under security/logins in Sql Management. I have updated the question to include an image.

Comment: @donstack I tried as you suggested, unfortunately it doesn't exist and times out. It was a good idea in any case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only see Refresh and Properties when you right click on Tables in Server Explorer, you probably need to install SQL Server Data Tools from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027 .

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013, it looks like these tools are for 2012. I'm doing some googling and I'm not finding one for the same version, is there a more recent version?

Comment: Even I don't seem to find any later than the October release. Try installing the latest that you can find.

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113069/visual-studio-2012-mvc-local-db-add-table-menu-option-missing

Comment: I've installed it, and while it doesn't seem to have the desired effect on 2013 (in fact I'm getting package errors and can't seem to open anything or have basic functionality) I just remembered that I do have a 2012 installation and it seems to be working on 2012. I'm able to progress further into my assignment. (So even though this isn't technically the answer I was looking for I'm choosing it because it means I'm not going to fail my class.) Thank you!

Comment: To follow up on this further, after I finished my assignment in 2012 I repaired my 2013 installation. Now my 2013 installation can run the program I just made and it also lets me right click and add new tables. This is probably as close as we get to the correct solution

Answer (score 6):

Use `update` after you create the table, don't use `save`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar "Create Table" not showing up (only "refresh" and "Properties" are left) for a right click on the empty Table in Data Connections.

I installed SQL server data tools and it is working! Thanks!