# Can't edit in sql database in Visual studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2008-r2

I use SQL Server 2008 R2. I made a database in the SQl management studio and I designed the table. 
When I opened the database in Visual Studio 2013 I couldn't edit anything in the database.

See this pic:

[image: Embedded Image]

What should I do ?

Comment: Are you using the same SQL or Windows identity in VS as you used in SSMS?

Comment: I didn't understand.. 
I just use VS 2013 and Sql Server 2008 I didn't download anything else

Comment: VS =Visual Studio, SSMS = SQL Server Management Studio. These are the tools you are using. I'm trying to determine if the identity you connect with in VS does not have rights to ALTER. Do this query in both tools and compare results:   SELECT CURRENT_USER

Comment: In SSMS I get "dbo" .. 
I can't make a query in VS it's locked

Comment: Reference this SO question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454438/microsoft-sql-server-creating-new-table-in-server-explorer

Answer (score 1):

VS 2013 suppurt sql 2012 ,2014 for design table

you can use menu 'tools - > sql -> new query...'

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
I just reinstalled the visual Studio and it worked 
thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

For future readers [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn864412) and download SSDTSetup.exe