# Edit Database in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Hi the add table option is gone in visual studio 2013.
As suggested in another thred i tried repaired visual studio with no result.

This is what my meny looks like

[image]

And this is what it should look like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server Data Tools from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) .

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113069/visual-studio-2012-mvc-local-db-add-table-menu-option-missing) as well.

Comment: thanks your second link, i found i link to download it manually.
I visited the first link before and there it says that it should be included, but obviously not in mine.