# Doesn`t show add new table option in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've VS2012 Ultimate. When I want to add new table with right click on tables folder on server explore it doesn`t show add new table option:

[image]

Comment: did you tried refreshing the schema.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 MVC Local DB Add Table menu option missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113069/visual-studio-2012-mvc-local-db-add-table-menu-option-missing)